# Azure Resource Manager provisioning workflow

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to setup an automated workflow for some applications using Azure Resource Manager. We would like to be able to run a script that will deploy infrstructure and applications on windows server. We will certainly use windows-server-2012 but it's not mandatory as the image is windows.

The documentation point to the infrastructure setup but after it's like black hole. I can't really find post talking of windows automated provisioning. Is there some best practices ?

- Should do it be hand: I setup a windows VM and add something like Chef/Puppet/... After the ARM deployment is done I use the ARM output to trigger some provisioning ?
- Or is there an ARM provisioning tool to do that ?

As the question is really generique, if you could just point me to some documentation/name, it would be really fine. It's better if it's coming from someone that already have go through this :D

Comment: Unfortunately tool/tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. There's documentation on the Azure site, and there are many public ARM templates in the Azure github repo, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates), which might give you ideas for installing applications (as many of those ARM templates do exactly that).

Comment: It should be a good starting point. Thank you @DavidMakogon.